# How Much Power do I need to give to these Servos?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, servo

I am building a robot to control a Wiimote Controller, or a Wii Classic Controller, as part of a larger machine learning project. I've found a set of parts that should work for my purposes. However, I've got little experience with electronics. I believe I've found parts that should work together just fine, but I don't know how much power I should put into this.

The Robot will be comprised of:

1 [Polulu Micro Maestro 6-Channel USB Controller](https://www.pololu.com/product/1350/resources)

6 [Spektrum 2.9g Linear Long Throw Servos](https://www.spektrumrc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=SPMSH2040L)

1 Wooden Mounting Set

The Maestro Controller will be powered off my computer's USB Port, so it's not much of a concern. However, the servos cannot draw power from USB (The Controller doesn't support that option, and I don't think it can supply nearly enough even if it could).

I'm uncertain on how I need to setup the power supply for the Servos. I'm planning to do it with a battery if possible. I should be able to feed them straight through the Microcontroller... but I don't know what voltage the battery needs to supply. I also don't know if there are any secondary concerns I should think about.

Comment: You need to find out what the max current draw is of the servos. That link does not say. So either look for more data, or test them your self (need to test under 'heavy' load) Then base your power supply off of that.  Servos need around 4 volts.

Comment: Those are specialized servos for ultra lightweight aircraft; probably not what you want for a robotics project.  They're quite a bit weaker and 2-3 times more expensive than ordinary servos.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that the linear servos you linked are unusual in that they are designed to run on a 1S lipo (3.2 to 4.2v). Most servos are designed to run on 5v, which is simpler if you want to use anything *besides* a lipo to run the servo.

The servos, and servo controller you linked should be compatible. You'll additionally need a power supply that can supply between 3.2 and 4.2 volts. Either a simple lipo (you'll also need a charger), or a wall wart like [this one](https://smile.amazon.com/DEMASLED-Output-Switching-Supply-LISTED/dp/B00HQ1F2OA). If you go with a wall wart, you'll have to cut the end off and solder a servo connector onto it so that you can plug it into your servo controller.

Comment: Actually, it is not clear that they are compatible, unless the generator produces 3.3v signal pulses (it is documented to produce 5v serial output, but the servo pulses don't seem to be specified), or the low voltage servo is known to tolerate 5v ones.  It's quite often to use a 3.3v MCU to feed 5v servos, but unless that is explicitly known to be the case here one can't assume.

Answer (score 0):

PRODUCT SPECS:

Voltage:
    3.2 - 4.2V

18650 LiPo cell and holder.

I est.  around 2400mAh and might expect 1A peaks during motion per motor, so unless you have been advised by supplier, I doubt your PIC ESC can drive the current.   Shouldn't it be something like this ? https://www.spektrumrc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=SPMAS6410NBL

Comment: Would [these](https://www.amazon.com/EBL-lithium-Rechargeable-Batteries-3000mAh/dp/B0129F9BXK/ref=zg_bs_10112773011_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=B07NV0VV29JS3VM4QS1W) batteries be sufficient?

Comment: Reviews appear ok  get more and a better charger? https://www.amazon.com/EBL-Lithium-ion-Discharge-Rechargeable-Batteries/dp/B016ZPBHAK/ref=pd_sbs_23_3/143-4248377-5362244?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B016ZPBHAK&pd_rd_r=4XPTT44K7B8H54KC5H60&pd_rd_w=FQ7Mj&pd_rd_wg=04IQD&psc=1&refRID=4XPTT44K7B8H54KC5H60  then recharge after 50% use

Comment: Thank you on that one.

Can you break down the acronym PIC ESC. I'm new to robotics and controllers, and I'm not familiar with the shortened forms.

Comment: PIC is Microchip's brandname  used  to interface with the ESC (elect. servo controller) to   your USB port ,  ESC is the controller like link in answer , which may be ok

Comment: No.  There is no ESC involved here.  An ESC is an Electronic **Speed** Controller, ie for a brushed or brushless motor. None here.

Comment: If See link  , I suggested he needs an ESC and  not try to servo control the motor with uC logic drivers

Comment: Yes but my point was obvious , there needs to be